# How to keep data on XSP page while calling history.back()?

Tags: xpages

I have a page, that is a search form (lets say - search.xsp). If document are found, multiple links are generated to document links (item.xsp).

I would like to keep search preferences in case user uses "back" button, so I can serve him with last searched data by him.

There is context.redirectToPrevious() method, but I can't use it because of on-load redirect.

So, how can I achieve that? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In my experience, maintaining state when the user clicks the back button is best handled by designing your application as a single page application. You would do this in XPages with the dynamic content control. The Mastering XPages book (2nd ed) has lots of info on this control.

Answer (score 0):

can't you store the search queries made in a sessionscope so you have them available when the user hits the back button? you can check the available values via the debug toolbar

Comment: Hmm. I think sessionscope solution wouldn't work on multiple tabs in browse, would it?